# Shared Preference issues in released apk

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences, release

When I use shared Preference in my flutter app the released apk doesn't show any thing on my phone ,the code is

`

```
String encodedMap = prefs.getString('timeData');
Map<String,dynamic> decodedMap = json.decode(encodedMap);
print(decodedMap);
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

add shared_preferences to `dependencies` in pubspec.yaml not `dev_dependencies`:

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences:
```

make sure you use `await` and make an instance of SharedPreferences

```
initPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String encodedMap = await prefs.getString('timeData');
    Map<String,dynamic> decodedMap = json.decode(encodedMap);
    print(decodedMap);
}
```

and if you didnt set anything in prefs, you cant load it because its empty.

Comment: yes , I did all of that and it's working well on the emulator.

Comment: did you check pubspec too?!

Comment: yes , i added this    shared_preferences: ^2.0.15

Comment: Add your full snippet, maybe we findout

Comment: Run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`

Comment: I got this when I build an APK  ' Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
 '